# Symfony2: saving on db using ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

i'm studying the Symfony2 framework and i want to create a simple application with a very simple form  (one text field) and save the submitted data (using ajax) in a very simple table on the database. My goal is to view and update (in the same page using ajax) the entire database table every time a new submitted data is sent and saved.
This is what i done until now, i'm not able to save anything and a 500

> DefaultController.php

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $item = New Item();
        $form = $this->createForm(new ItemType(), $item,  array('action'=>$this->generateUrl('vendor_name_simple_homepage'),'method'=>'POST'));
        $form->add('Submit','submit',array('label'=>'Add'));
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $this->saveAction($item);
        }
        return $this->render('VendorNameSimpleBundle:Default:lista.html.twig',array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }
    public function saveAction($item){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($item);
        $em->flush();
        return new Response('success');
    }
}
```

> The JQuery script

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('form').submit(function(event) {
                    // prevents the browser from "following" the link
                    event.preventDefault();

                    var $url = $("form").attr("action");// + '.json';
                    var $value = $('#item_itemName').val();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: $url,
                        data: $value,
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('ul').html(data);
                        }/*,
                        dataType: 'json'*/
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

> EDIT: This is the Network console output, there is no error in the JS
>   console
>
> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO item (itemName)
>   VALUES (?)' with params [null]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
>   violation: 1048 Column 'itemName' cannot be null (500 Internal Server
>   Error)
>
> UPDATE: seems that the request is successfully sent but i can't access
>   (or i don't exactly know how to do) to the content request because the
>   controller receive this Request:

`/app_dev.php/myapp/path/ HTTP/1.1 Accept: / Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3 Cache-Control: no-cache Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 11 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 Cookie: PHPSESSID=qhou8f9lias0i9fh3besdpbii7 Host: localhost:8000 Pragma: no-cache Referer: http://localhost:8000/app_dev.php/myapp/path/ User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0 X-Php-Ob-Level: 1 X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest MyInputData`

Comment: Check console for errors.

Comment: What is the error in your javascript console ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overcomplicating it. I would suggest you to do all in one methods such as:

Note: This gives you general idea!

```
public function saveAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isXMLHttpRequest()) {
        $data = $request->request->get('request');
        $itemName = // Extract it from $data variable

        $item = NewItem();
        $item->setItemName($itemName);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($item);
        $em->flush();
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

You should also handle exceptions like this [Catching ORM, DBAL and PDO exceptions in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/nm7o/catching-orm-dbal-and-pdo-exceptions-in-symfony). Also look at [Symfony2cheatsheet](http://www.symfony2cheatsheet.com/) for nice stuff since you're learning.

Comment: can you be more specific? what do you mean with "// Get your data from ajax here and prepare it" ?

Comment: i think that the problem is not there, because $data is null

Comment: Then you need to solve front-end issue not symfony side of the story.

Comment: help me to understand, to extract the value from the $data variable, i have to write something like "$itemName = $data['theInputAttributeName'] right?

Comment: You need to do some research before asking questions. Why don't you just do `print_r($data)` to what it has in it? Then access it's content. While making AJAX call open your browser network tab to see what the response is so son....

Comment: if i'm asking here is because i have also done my research but i don't have the competence to troubleshoot in the right way. There are a lot of articles about sending forms with simfony2 but all of them have different implementation

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for certain until you post the exact error, but your `saveAction($item)` seems to expect an Object that you persist/flush into Doctrine, however it looks like you're not passing that along.

Ah my bad, see you've done that through the indexAction, I'd recommend to check if you post to the right url. In most browsers you can also see the XHR Requests to check what the exact error is the request gave you.

**Edit**
Thanks for your error, the item you're saving is the empty object you've created, make sure you save the item with the data you've retrieved, with this line:

```
$filledinItem = $form->getData();
```